# Dynamically Refresh Schema in SSAS tabular cube

Tags: ssas-tabular

Is there any command to refresh cube schema (Structure) every day before processing the SSAS tabular cube?

Requirement: Few column names in an object keeps changing(renaming) so, if we rename those columns in DB view, it should automatically reflect in Cube after overnight processing.

I tried adding ‘select * from an Object’ in cube table properties and processed cube.
Later, I tried to rename column name in view then processed cube, it failed due to  different column name.

Is it possible to dynamically refresh schema without manually changing structure via solution and re-deploy?

Please suggest

Answer (score 0):

This answer is not going to solve your issue, however best practice would be NOT to handle these changes in the SSAS Data Model. This should be a consistent layer for your users. I would handle these changes in the data base or source system end, maybe checking if a column exists, and if not adding a dummy row or some other process.